# Using opencv's calcHist with UMat for calculating a percentile

Tags: opencv, opencl, percentile

I am writing a function that gets a given percentile of an image (gray). 
For that I wanted to use calcHist() with UMat in order to accelerate my code. 
But in all the ways I've tried to do that - it took much more time when I used UMat (instead of Mat).

I am new here - any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
int CalcPercentile(UMat gray, float fPercent)
{
    int hSize = 256;    
    UMat hist;
    Mat histMat;

    calcHist(vector<UMat>{gray}, vector<int>{0}, UMat(), hist, vector<int>{hSize}, vector<float>{0,255}); 
    int iNumPixels = gray.rows * gray.cols;
    float fSumFreqNeeded = (float)iNumPixels * fPercent;

    histMat = hist.getMat(ACCESS_READ); // or: hist.copyTo(histMat);

    int iSumFreq = 0, iVal;

    for (iVal = 0; iVal < iHistSize; iVal++)
    {
        int iCurrFreq = (int)(histMat.at<float>(iVal));
        iSumFreq += iCurrFreq;
        if (iSumFreq >= fSumFreqNeeded)
            break;
    }
    return iVal;
}
```

a corresponding function with Mat instead of UMat was much faster. 
(But my code uses UMat gray image as input - and converting to Mat again takes too much time).

Comment: Yes, there is significant overhead moving the data to and from the graphics card memory. You're not going to gain anything (more of the opposite, as you found) if all you want is to calculate a histogram of an image. It only makes sense when you have enough work to do, so that the capability of the GPU to do lots of calculations in parallel outweighs this overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
I was surprised to realize that because the case of a histogram - parallel computing seems quite straight forward. 
So I though there would be a fast way for that with UMat.